# Regular expression in HTML - Command OR

Tags: html, regular-language

I have this:

```
<input type="text" name="funkce<%=i %>" value="" size="20" data-toogle="tooltip" title="Vlož hodnoty a-z o maximální délce 3 znaky." style="width: 50px; padding: 2px" required maxlength="3"  pattern="([a-z]{1,3})|(([a-z]{1}[\s,]+)*[a-z]{1})" />
```

It is not working I need control input for two types string.
I need insert example "a,b,c" or "abc", but or (|) in pattern is not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is working. It is checked onsubmit, not onkeydown nor onkeypress.

However, the pattern is nondeterministic. It should be writen in such a way that every character is matched by at most one subpattern. In this case, deterministic version is: `[a-z](([a-z]{1,2})|([\s,]+[a-z])*)`

Also `maxlength="3"` will not work with input `a,b,c`.

Comment: Thank you, so much.